# Grails REST Security - Expired Password

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, passwords

I have an app up and running with REST authentication working but now want to add password expiry (this will be done via a quartz job setting a property on the default User class - boolean passwordExpired)

Can someone point me in the right direction to handle an expired password exception returning something like a 403 to indicate to enter a new password on the front end rather than a 401.

I am seeing the following in the logs:

```
DEBUG userdetails.DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks  - User account credentials have     expired
DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication failed: User credentials have     expired
DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenAuthenticationFailureHandler  - Sending status code 401 and header WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
```

Assume I have to override a method somewhere but I am new to grails and not sure on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.

For reference to anybody else: - 
1) Disabled Bearer token support (not sure if this was needed but its working)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
```

2) Create a new class that implements

```
class CustomRestAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {@
    Override
    void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response, AuthenticationException exception) {
        def statuscode = HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN
            ...
            // do something based on the exception message and change the status or add a     message to response.body
    }
```

3) Add the bean to resources.groovy

```
beans = {

  restAuthenticationFailureHandler(CustomRestAuthenticationFailureHandler) {

  }
}
```